# Find the following limit: $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}$

Tags: limits

Find the following limit:

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}$$

I think use Taylor's expansion give $\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n$ or there is a workaround, but I do not know.

Comment: You are on the good track. But, first extract factor n^(1/n) in the numerator, raise to power and use Taylor for the remaining.

Answer (score 4):

Let $b_n=\sqrt[n]{n}-1=n^{1/n}-1$ and $a_n=\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}$ so that
$$a_n=\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}=\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-2+1\right)^n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{e}^{n\ln(1+2b_n)}$$
For $n\to \infty, \;b_n\to 0$ because $b_n=\operatorname{e}^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1$ and for $n\to \infty$, $\frac{\ln n}{n}\to 0$.
So for $n\to\infty$ we have $\ln(1+2b_n)\sim 2b_n$, and $b_n=n^{1/n}-1=\operatorname{e}^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1\sim 1+\frac{\ln n}{n}-1=\frac{\ln n}{n}$ so that
$$
n\ln(1+2b_n)\sim n2b_n\sim n2\frac{\ln n}{n}=\ln n^2.
$$
Finally for $n\to\infty$
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{e}^{n\ln(1+2b_n)}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{e}^{\ln n^2}=\frac{n^2}{n^2}=1
$$
that is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}=1
$$

Comment: The equivalents used in this answer are not enough to deduce the result. One needs a control on the terms neglected to make sure they translate into the limit 1 at the end.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\sqrt[n]{n}-1}{n^{2/n}}\right)^n \\
&= \operatorname{e}^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}-1}{n^{2/n}}-1\right)n}=\operatorname{e}^{-\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n^{1/n}-1}{n^{1/n}}\right)^2\cdot n}\\
&= \operatorname{e}^{-\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1}{{\frac{\ln n}{n}}}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^2\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2/n}}\cdot n}\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{-1\cdot 1\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln^2n}{n}}=\operatorname{e}^{0}= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Might want to sort out the formatting. Looks an bit wrong

Comment: This result is true! Thanks you!

Comment: @alexjo, Thanks you!

Comment: @medicu It seem's that some is missing in the proof...

Comment: @alexjo. I checked and I have seen mistakes.
We used $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$

Comment: @medicu I see...your answer is wrong..

Comment: It may be wrong. So something is total exclus.Te please show me what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @medicu you missed the log in the exponentiation on the second line and the other calculation seems wrong at the beginning of the 2nd line...

Comment: @medicu did you check your answer?

Comment: @Mrnhan this answer is wrong..

Comment: @alexjo: I just said  this result is right

Comment: @alexjo. If $\lim_{x\to \alpha} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to \alpha} g(x) =\infty $ then there is "the shortcut" $\lim_{x\to \alpha} (f(x))^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to \alpha} (f(x)-1)g(x)} $